# running web2py scheduler in production

Tags: python, deployment, web2py, production-environment

I know that I can run the scheduler manually by using

```
python web2py.py -K myapp
```

But where should this be specified in production environment? I am using standard web2py deployment script for apache, on ubuntu.

Comment: For the production you have to use [mod_wsgi](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#mod_wsgi). This will work with apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ubuntu 12.04 I make it manually:

1. in **/etc/init** directory create **web2py-scheduler.conf** file:

   ```
   description     "Web2py scheduler"
   start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
   stop on runlevel [!2345]

   respawn
   respawn limit 8 60

   exec sudo -u user <path_to_web2py>/web2py.py -K <your_app>
   ```
2. in **/etc/init.d** exec:

   ln -s /lib/init/upstart-job web2py-scheduler
3. (optional, only if you want manual startup) in **/etc/init** directory create the **web2py-scheduler.override** file:

   ```
   manual
   ```

Comment: Why is respawn limit 8 60 ? Is sudo really necessary?

Comment: The respawn limit is a good choice for me, more 8 times in 1 minute means there is some problem and the scheduler startup is a little slow.

Comment: The sudo is important for security reasons. So web2py scheduler run as unprivileged user.

Answer (score 8):

Just to round the picture. Using Debian or other Linux distributions after 2015, the way to go is [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/). For systemd the following steps have to be taken:
Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/web2py-sched.service`
Containing the following

```
[Unit]
Description=Web2Py scheduler service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/www-data/web2py/web2py.py -K <yourapp>
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then install the service calling:

```
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/web2py-sched.service
```

Comment: To start the service you can call systemctl:

`systemctl start /etc/systemd/system/web2py-sched`

Comment: Or `sudo service web2py-sched start`

Answer (score 1):

Please see
[Web2Py Book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#Start-the-scheduler-as-a-Linux-service--upstart-)
which worked for me running Ubuntu 14:

> ### Start the scheduler as a Linux service (upstart)
>
> To install the scheduler as a permanent daemon on Linux (w/ Upstart), put the following into **/etc/init/web2py-scheduler.conf**, assuming your web2py instance is installed in *user*'s home directory, running as *user*, with app *myapp*, on network interface eth0.

```
description "web2py task scheduler"
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on shutdown
respawn limit 8 60 # Give up if restart occurs 8 times in 60 seconds.
exec sudo -u <user> python /home/<user>/web2py/web2py.py -K <myapp>
respawn
```

> You can then start/stop/restart/check status of the daemon with:

```
sudo start web2py-scheduler
sudo stop web2py-scheduler
sudo restart web2py-scheduler
sudo status web2py-scheduler
```